# IPhone app name on app store is diffrent than iphone device

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

My Iphone app name is not in english.
I set the name under Product name in xcode.
On the iphone device it's O.K.

When I uploaded the binary to iTunes Connect, they "insist" to write the app name in english only, well i thought this will be like and "id" for the app, not the display name.

well, i was wrong, now on the app store the app name is on english, and in the iphone it's in the other language that i wanted.

So, Where I can change the app name on the appstore ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit an app update to change either the store name or the bundle display name.  The two do not need to be exactly the same.